# Burp Interception does not work for localhost in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, localhost, burp

I can't intercept requests made by `Chrome version 73.0.3683.86` to my localhost site.

- Local host site is running on IIS on `http://127.0.0.3:80`
- Burp proxy lister is default one on `127.0.0.1:8080`
- Interception rules are default one as well
- In my LAN settings, "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" is not enabled

When Interception is turned ON and I reload page in `Chrome` browser, no request is "caught" by Burp, my local site loads and only the external requests are intercepted, such as loading external scripts from CDN.

Also under "Proxy" > "HTTP History" there is only request to external sites, and all requests to `http://127.0.0.3:80` are not recorded.

When I reload same page by `Internet Explorer 11`, initial `GET` request is intercepted by Burp, as expected. Also "Proxy" > "HTTP History" shows all the requests to local site `http://127.0.0.3:80`

What is the problem with the `Chrome`? Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this behavior as well, in Chromium 72. Updated from 67 after the recent 0day and unit tests with local test apps started failing with Chromium. have some remote test apps as well, and those pass without issue. With Firefox, all tests still pass.

Comment: @Stephen Roebuck Thanks for sharing, so it seems like Chrome bypass proxy for local requests regardless of the setting.

Comment: Same issue here. I am running Chrome 72.0.3626.121. Firefox is fine. Chrome intercepts anything but localhost whether I use the system proxy set for 127.0.0.1:8080 (or any other port) or ProxySwitchy. This started for me within the last two weeks.

Answer (score 12):

Found the solution late yesterday. I am using the Chrome extension ProxySwitchy, but it doesn't matter if you use that or the system proxy configuration. The solution works the same way.

[image: Chrome ProxySwitchy Extension]

[image: Windows 10 Proxy Settings]

Comment: An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I wish I we had more explanations. This solved my issue too. Just by configuring **ONLY** `<-loopback>` in "direct" option for Proxy Switcher

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by adding an entry in /etc/hosts file like below

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   
127.0.0.1   somehostname
```

Now burp will intercept request from `somehostname`

Comment: Seems new version of chrome doesn't check some type of sites for ssl connection and also doesn't use proxy for them. But if you access to site via http.//somehostname:3000 it will work

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Chrome are you using?

Have you tried using the FoxyProxy Chrome extension?

As a workaround, you could modify the hosts file on your machine.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 Thanks for tips, will give it a try and get back.

Comment: I added a my localhost site to the hosts file and tried to use FoxyProxy extentsion, but chrome skipped proxy for localhost requests.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when I upgraded from Opera 58.0 to 60.0. I think that this is Chrome related, because I've also experienced it in all other Chrome browsers. Opera 58 utilizes Chrome 71.0.3578.98. Opera 60 utilizes version Chrome 73.0.3683.103. Something was definitely updated in Chrome between these versions to cause this problem to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subtract the implicit bypass rules defined in Chrome (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/docs/proxy.md#Implicit-bypass-rules)

> Requests to certain hosts will not be sent through a proxy, and will
>   instead be sent directly.
>
> We call these the implicit bypass rules. The implicit bypass rules
>   match URLs whose host portion is either a localhost name or a
>   link-local IP literal. Essentially it matches:
>
> > localhost
> >
> > *.localhost [::1]
> >
> > 127.0.0.1/8
> >
> > 169.254/16
> >
> > [FE80::]/10

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/docs/proxy.md#Bypass-rule_Subtract-implicit-rules

> Whereas regular bypass rules instruct the browser about URLs that
>   should not use the proxy, Subtract Implicit Rules has the opposite
>   effect and tells the browser to instead use the proxy.

In order to be able to proxy through the loopback interface, you have to add the entry

**<-loopback>**

in the list of hosts for which you don't want to a proxy. It is a bit confusing, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't enabled socks proxy option, it happened with me too and i found the solution when i disabled the socks proxy option, just make sure it's disabled!
Example:
[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

It helped me

I turned on this settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is many ways to proxy capture localhost ,try this on terminal

> ifconfig | grep "inet "
> it will give your private ip address and like(000.00.000.00) and you have to add (80)port and it become (000.00.000.00:80) so test in any browser that will be captured.